# Save data from array in variables-Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, moodle

I'm trying to display the data fetched from the database into a readable format but i'm getting it as
`Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Faculty of Law and Management [uni_id] => 12 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [name] => Faculty of Engineering [uni_id] => 13 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [name] => Faculty of Engineering [uni_id] => 13 ) ) 1` when i use `echo print_r($record);`.

**Code**

```
<?php

$record= $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT * FROM {faculty}');

if($record != NULL)
{
    echo print_r($record);
}

?>
```

How can i save data from each column into a variable so as i can display them in a table afterwards?

Comment: You need to either convert it into normal array and then iterate on that array or you can directly do that also.

Comment: Use flexible_table in Moodle. Look through the code for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this (suppose your array variable is `$array`):-

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr><tbody>"; // start table
foreach($array as $arr){ // start iteration
    echo "<tr><td>".$arr->id ."</td><td>".$arr->id ."</td></tr>"; // fetch value and set into table rows.
}
echo "</tbody></table>";//end table
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I've understood it. :)